# How to create FTP Site in IIS 7 using WMI and C# from ASP.Net Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ftp, wmi

I am working on a website provisioning system using IIS 7 (and IIS6) and using C# as development Tool (under .Net 3.5) using WMI.

I want to create FTP Site via code in C# using WMI. I cant want to use MWA(Microsoft.Web.Administration) because I have to support older version a.k.a IIS 6 as well. I believe its possible via WMI.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are talking about the IIS6 'compatible' FTP server or the new FTP 7/7.5?

Comment: I am not talking about the IIS 6 FTP Compatibility mode. I have installed "FTP Publishing Service for IIS 7" which is available as an installer from Microsoft from here:

http://www.iis.net/expand/FTP

The Problem is : When we create even an ftp site, it appears in the "Sites" tree. In terms of logical representation, The IIS Tree now contains ftp sites as well as regular web sites in "W3SVC" Node.

Comment: In IIS 6, regular websites used to be in W3SVC Node and Ftp Sites used to be in "MSFTPSVC" NOde. Therefore, it was easy to query websites and ftp sites separately and thus perform operations on them.

Programmatically speaking, the IIsFTPServer, IIsFTPService, IIsFTPVirtualDir Classes for WMI are available for IIS 6.0. Bu they dont work with IIS 7.0 in WMi using C#>


The tree structure in IIS 6.0 as per my understanding is:

IIS Root > W3SVC > Websites

IIS Root > MSFTPSVC > FTP Sites

IN Iss 7.0 , however, 

IIS Root > W3SVC > WebSites

IIS Root > W3SVC > FTp Sites.

Comment: So when i enumerate websites, i am getting the list of FTP Sites as well and list of FTP Sites is empty which is not correct (as i used to traverse the W3SVC node for websites and MSFTPSVC Node for the FTP Sites)